# POST Requests with axios not sending parameters

Tags: symfony, vue.js, axios

I am trying to POST some data from Vue.js to a backend based on Symfony using the following code.

```
       updateQuestion : function() {
            axios.post('/staff/question/api/' + this.id,{
                    id : 'test',
                    name : 'sree'
            })
                .then( response => {

                console.log(response);
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
```

However, the parameters that I am attaching to the POST request are not reaching my controller. So, I tried the alternate format for POST requests and still, the parameters are not reaching the controller. Please tell me what's wrong.

Alternate format:

```
 updateQuestion : function() {
            axios({

                method : 'POST',
                url : '/staff/question/api/' + this.id,
                data: {
                    id : 'test',
                    name : 'sree'
                }

            })
                .then( response => {

                console.log(response);
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
```

Comment: what do u mean by `controller` ? is it a `symfony` thing? like an endpoint?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint where the POST request is handled.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I also encountered this problem!
My post data was found in the controller:

```
$request->getContent();
```

My vue script

```
onSubmit() {
  axios.post('/test/post/data', { test: "test" })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
},
```

My Symfony controller:

```
public function postData(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    return $this->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Found the request data in ```$request->getContent()```. This was something new to me. Is there any explanation why the request data is missing in ```$request->request->all()``` ?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The @Bloops proposal should also be considered :)

Answer (score 5):

Install FOSRestBundle to solve this problem.

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle
```

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

Using this bundle, incoming json requests will be automatically translated into an array, directly available in `$request->request->all()` or `$request->request->get('myparam')`.

Documentation excerpt:

This bundle provides various tools to rapidly develop RESTful API's & applications with Symfony. Features include:

- A View layer to enable output and format agnostic Controllers
- A custom route loader to generate url's following REST conventions
- Accept header format negotiation including handling for custom mime types
- RESTful decoding of HTTP request body and Accept headers
- Exception controller for sending appropriate HTTP status codes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$request->getContent();` you can do the following in your JavaScript file to be able to use `$request->request->all()` in your backend.

I needed this for writing tests, since `$request->getContent();` is empty in my tests.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('id', 123456);
params.append('name', 'some name');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/staff/question/api/' + this.id,
  data: params
});
```

See also: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195#issuecomment-347021460

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing wrong with your syntax. But check this.id - if you are not doing any mistake and this.id is undefined, or something. And if this.id is ok, then log complete request in controller and look for data.

```
updateQuestion: function () {
  axios
  .post('/staff/question/api/' + this.id, {
    id: 'test',
    name: 'sree'
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
}
```

Comment: this.id is defined and the request hits endpoint corresponding to the value of the id. However, the request parameters are not reaching the end point.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `$request->getContent();` but handle it like `$_POST` vars in general like user6748331 suggested, here a function:

utils.js (or whatever):

```
export function preparePostData(data) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // for the sake of editor not screaming
            formData.append(key, data[key]);
        }
    }

    return formData;
}
```

somewhere in your frontend:

```
import {preparePostData} from "utils";
const data = {
  firstname: "Foo",
  lastname: "Bar"
}

const postData = preparePostData(data);
axios.post("/whereever", postData);
```

In your Symfony Controller:

```
$data = $request->request->all();
```

P.S. This is just for plain objects. If you want to post arrays and stuff you may need to `json_decode` in Symfony as well. or change the `preparePostData` function to make it recursive.