# Symfony + VueJs + Axios = No send form parameters

Tags: php, symfony, vue.js, axios

I am using Symfony 4, VueJs 2 and Axios to send my form with Ajax. The form is sent without apparent problems, but it seems that the input data of my form are not sent with it.

Curiosity: I did it but with jQuery Ajax and works really fine.

I already tried this 2017 solution but does not work for me: [POST Requests with axios not sending parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056498/post-requests-with-axios-not-sending-parameters)

*index.html*

```
<form id="form" @submit.prevent="sendForm">
    <input type="text" v-model="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let form = new Vue({
        el: "#form",
        data: {
            name: ""
        },
        methods: {
            sendForm: function () {
                axios
                    .get("/send", this.data)
                    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

*homeController.php*

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index() {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/send", name="send")
     */
    public function sendForm(Request $request) {
        $name = $request->query->get("name");
        return new Response($name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony try with: `$request->getContent()`.

Exemple:

```php
// ...
class HomeController extends AbstractController {
    //...
    /**
     * @Route("/send", name="send")
     */
    public function sendForm(Request $request) {
        // Decode data with json_decode()
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $name = $data['name'];

        return $this->json($name);
    }
    //...
}
```

Enjoy!